# Modify the number of channels in pre-trained CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have trained a CNN model with input size `(None, 256, 256, 1)` and saved this mthe model using `model.save()` method.

In this model, I have used `GlobalAveragePooling2D()` before connecting to a dense layer, which in turn leads to the output of three values.

I want the whole model as it is (i.e., the same architecture and weights) but a different number of channels in the input.

For example, how to change the input size be changed from `(None, 256, 256, 1)` to `(None, 256, 256, 2).`

I have tried as follows, but it raised an Attribute error,

```
from tensorflow import keras
cnn_model = keras.models.load_model(filepath=model_dir)
cnn_model.input = (None, 256, 256, 2)

AttributeError: Can't set the attribute "input", likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a different name.
```

Do I have to build another model(containing the same architecture and weights) from the existing model? If so, how to do this?

or else
Do I have to train another model, starting from the weights of this model (This is not desirable, but if there is no way, I can resort to it.)

Answer (score 0):

it is easy and that is supposed to re-training models for new values for correct results of prediction or working

1. You can create 4 channels input picture and modify a 3-channels picture but the results are working because some colors influent the image patterns recognitions.
2. I recommended using the same input format including channels, I know some bugs in some programs they detected image patterns, open the images to see if the body does not contain only pixels, or read it without labels and order.
3. Use concatenate model with Priorities and scores.

Sample Concatenated model with priority and scores << You had something works then continue use it when build something to sufficient working >>

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.tif')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.tif')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
for file in files.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(1)
    
for file in files_2.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image = tfio.experimental.image.decode_tiff(image, index=0)
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [32,32], method='nearest')
    list_file.append(image)
    list_label.append(9)
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
first_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=( 32, 32, 4 ), name="first input" )
second_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=( 32, 32, 4 ), name="second input" )

priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.)(first_input)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.)(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225))(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False))(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96))(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu')(priority_pred)
priority_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="priority")(priority_pred)


department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(second_input)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225))(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False))(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96))(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu')(department_pred)
department_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="department")(department_pred)


# Instantiate an end-to-end model predicting both priority and department
model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=[first_input, second_input],
    outputs=[priority_pred, department_pred],
)

model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,  loss={
                                            "priority": tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                                            "department": tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                                        },
                                    loss_weights={"priority": 1.0, "department": 0.2},
                                    metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

priority_targets = tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)
dept_targets = tf.constant(list_label, shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)
                        
history = model.fit( {"first input": tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64), 
                        "second input": tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64)},
                        
                     {"priority": priority_targets, "department": dept_targets},

                        batch_size=100, epochs=50 )
```

Output : Modified matrixes and return for correct display values, model is working with different priority but 2 outputs concatenated.

```
Epoch 49/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_loss: 0.0000e+00 - department_loss: 0.0000e1/1 [==============================] - 0s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_loss: 0.0000e+00 - department_loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_accuracy: 0.5000 - department_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 50/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_loss: 0.0000e+00 - department_loss: 0.0000e1/1 [==============================] - 0s 54ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_loss: 0.0000e+00 - department_loss: 0.0000e+00 - priority_accuracy: 0.5000 - department_accuracy: 0.5000
```